# font detect software

Tags: fonts

I want to know if there is any software out there that works on the same principle as myfonts.com and whatfontis.com with the difference that the database of fonts it a searches from is from the computers font folder.

Your looking for a font which you might already have on the computer or something similar. Instead of going through all your fonts one by one use a software to do it for you.

Comment: You may want to look at the website APIs, maybe there is a function that returns the font name based on an image stored in your PC. Which I doubt (for economic and security reasons). I don't recommend offline solutions, they are slow and depend on cloud based services

Answer (score 1):

You could try this software:
[Find my Font Free](http://find-my-font-free.software.informer.com/)

or you could try asking your query at [Software Recommendation StackExchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: +1 for [Find my Font](http://www.typophile.com/node/92904)!